# Rotating images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slider

Just wondering if someone can help me code the following.

I want to use a fading effect to rotate a series of images (7 in total), within the CSS and code already defined below:

```
<style="text/css">
.rotate {float: left;width: 160px;height: 215px;background-color: #FFFFFF;border: 2px solid #0066CC;margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;text-align: center;overflow: hidden;}
</style>


<div class="rotate">
    <span>
        <a href="#">
            <img border="0" src="catimage.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="" class="" />
        </a>
    </span>
    <div onclick="javascript:document.location.href='/';">
        <a href="/"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me code this.

Many thanks

Comment: it is tagged with jQuery

Comment: @Bil `fading effect to rotate` what does it mean ? your `style` tag is missing `type` attribute :)

Comment: the above is the basic HTML that is already on the site, but basically I need to rotate a series of images within this block. So, I have found the following: http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/easy_jquery_auto_image_rotator.html however, I cannot code the CSS etc to ensure that this work within the HTML and CSS already on the site and need some help amending this script to work on the site please.

Comment: I have been trying to do this now for hours and fail each time; therefore help is required please.

Comment: @Bill you mean something like: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html? Because that's basically what the code in that site you linked to do

Comment: @Bill Johnson; you're going to have more luck getting better answers if you break this into smaller questions; there's a lot here to answer.

Comment: Do you mean 'rotate' as in actually spin the images around on screen as if they were a pinwheel? Or rotate as in turn them into a slideshow and show one after another with a cross-fade in between?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the jQuery Rotate extension.  This sounds like it might be what you are looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

Comment: Hi, I have altered many; however, I need some help coding this to work within the parameters already defined in the CSS and HTML shown please

Answer (score 2):

I found this jQuery plugin that's apparently capable of rotating images by a given angle AND works in all browsers. I haven't tried it, but it's a starting point.

http://wilq32.adobeair.pl/jQueryRotate/Wilq32.jQueryRotate.html

If you don't mind your code working in webkit browsers only, rotating can be done in CSS only, using the CSS transition. Here's a demo with code:

http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/581_cssTransitions/demos.html

Comment: Hi, sure...but as mentioned I need someone to assit with the code and CSS of this to ensure it can be applied to the CSS already in place and the present positioning.

Comment: Um, wait... I'm not sure I understood the question OK... Do you need an image rotator (ie, changer), or do you want to rotate images by an angle?

Answer (score 1):

You can do rotation with CSS. The good news is that it works in just about every web browser out there. The bad news is, it's very much a browser-by-browser thing, so it takes quite a bit of code! For example, to rotate an element by 45 degrees, you would do something like this:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE9 */
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
transform: rotate(45deg);  /* plain CSS3 (for when it gets supported) */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
filter: progid\:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
```

You'll notice that the MS versions use bizarre numbers instead of degrees. These are (I believe) radians. You'll need to convert between them for any values you want to use.

Anyway, once you've got this worked out, it's (relatively) easy to use Javascript (or JQuery) to modify the styles at run-time, and get the rotation animated.

Enjoy.

Comment: Never EVER use the properties in that order!!! The one without the vendor prefix goes last, ALWAYS, otherwise you can produce hard to debug misbehaviour. Here's an article about it: http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/

Answer (score 0):

this is more of a combo question. if you make your own resource (ajax listener) to utilize php's [function.imagerotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) you will quickly solve your own problem.